# .ASPXAuth cookie never appears after log-in

Tags: cookies

I'm working on an existing ASP.Net website using forms authentication and was expecting to see .ASPXAUTH cookie in chrome dev tools once I've logged in, but I can't see it!
I can see the ASP.Net_SessionId cookie and various others, but just not the .ASPXAUTH one.

I have the following in my web.config in the system.web section.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="true" cookieSameSite="Strict"/>
</authentication>
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" sameSite="Strict" httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

Users can log in successfully, so the authentication is definitely happening.

I also can't see it in Firefox dev tools.

Should I still be able to see this cookie? I always used to be able to...

Comment: If you can't see dev tools it is likely something local to your system.  I would start by googling that.

Comment: @Nelles Just to clarify - I can see dev tools (Chrome and Firefox), but can't see the .ASPXAUTH cookie in dev tools.